# Emacs reindenting entire C++ buffer

Tags: emacs, indentation

i have a c++ code file but has pretty ugly indetation. How do i tell emacs to reapply indentation to the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the "indent entire buffer" code I place in my `~/.emacs.d/defuns.el` file. I took the extra step and bound it to a quick key, `C-x \`. This one also will clear out all your hanging whitspace as well as convert tab characters into their space equivalent representation.

```
(defun indent-buffer ()                                                                                                                                                            
  "Indents an entire buffer using the default intenting scheme."                                                                                                                   
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                    
  (point-to-register 'o)                                                                                                                                                           
  (delete-trailing-whitespace)                                                                                                                                                     
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)                                                                                                                                      
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max))                                                                                                                                               
  (jump-to-register 'o))                                                                                                                                                           

(global-set-key "\C-x\\" 'indent-buffer)
```

Edit, incorporating @JSONs suggestion below will give you a defun that looks like this instead:

```
(defun indent-buffer ()                                                                                                                                                            
  "Indents an entire buffer using the default intenting scheme."                                                                                                                   
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                    
  (save-excursion                                                                                                                                                                  
    (delete-trailing-whitespace)                                                                                                                                                   
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)                                                                                                                                    
    (untabify (point-min) (point-max))))
```

I tested this out and it works just like before. Thanks for pointing that out JSON.

Comment: Rather than point-to-register and jump-to-register, it might be better to use save-excursion to wrap the reformatting block.

Answer (score 33):

`C-x h C-M-\`

These two commands select the whole buffer and run `indent-region`.

Comment: So simpler that the above solution! But how do you actually hit \ key ??

Comment: I guess it depends on your keyboard layout. I'm using ESC as Meta, so the last part of the chord is `ESC C-\`. Mac users might need an additional setup for treating Alt as Meta.

Answer (score 5):

Select the entire buffer and do M-x indent-region

See [this guide](http://www.dansanderson.com/blog/2007/07/indenting-source-code-in-emacs.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun iwb ()
  "indent whole buffer"
  (interactive)
  (delete-trailing-whitespace)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))
```

You can use this little macro(i copied this from http://emacsblog.org/2007/01/17/indent-whole-buffer/)